# Java compiling a program on OS X, shows NoclassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I was compiling a java program on Mac OS X, and I have a problem with `java Helloworld.java`.

It shows: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError:Helloworld.java`

How can I fix it?

Comment: please explain your problem more. Show the code where the error happens.

Comment: Your "HelloWorld" class is probably either missing (it never compiled), mis-spelled (for example, "HelloWorld.class" instead of "Helloworld" or "hElLoWoRlD"), or in the wrong directory (for example, if you compiled with a package).  STRONG SUGGESTION: get an IDE like [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx) - it will make it much easier to focus on "background" problems like this, and let you focus on "Java".

Comment: First i complied a file Helloworld.java with javac it passed and i run a file with a $java Helloworld for the next finally after press enter terminal shown me like my describe

Comment: Edit you question to include the code and the command line you are running please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do This:

1) Edit your Program:

```
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println ("Hello World");
  }

}
```

2) Make sure `public class HelloWorld` is spelled "HelloWorld".  Make sure `public static void main (String[] args)` is spelled exactly like you see.

3) Compile:

`$ javac HelloWorld.java`

4) You should see *NO* error messages.  You *SHOULD* see a new class file:

```
$ ls -l HelloWorld*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paulsm paulsm 425 Jul  5 23:56 HelloWorld.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paulsm paulsm 119 Jul  5 23:56 HelloWorld.java
```

5) Run the file.  Make sure you do *NOT* add ".java" in your command:

```
$ java HelloWorld
Hello World
```

Please post back if this works.

Please consider getting an IDE.  I'd recommend Eclipse: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx